# Using QSlider to change the value of a variable

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I'm trying to use `QSlider` to change the value of a variable,

```
 #include <QSlider>

class MainThread : public QWidget{
Q_OBJECT
public:
MainThread(QWidget *parent=0);
private slots:
    void setValue(double);
private:
QSlider *slider; 
};

MainThread::MainThread(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent){
    slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal,0);
    connect(&slider, SIGNAL((slider->valueChanged())),
             this, SLOT(setValue(double))); // here's my  problem 
    ...
}
```

My question is how can I connect the `SIGNAL` of the slider to the `setValue(double)` SLOT.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why didn't you read Qt docs? There is "getting started" tutorial where you would learn how to use Qt signals and slots

Comment: I did and th it's just a part of my code and I've been using the SLOTS and SIGNAL but it doesn't work with QSLIDER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

slider is already a pointer, e.g. remove the '&'

```
connect( slider, SIGNAL((slider->valueChanged())), this, SLOT(setValue(double)) );
```

Edit: This won't work, since the signal has no argument.
Rename the setValue(double) to setValue() and get the value from the slider with slider->value().

Comment: thanks samuel , it solve the syntax error but I still have a compilation error

Comment: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void         __thiscall MainThread::setValue(int)

Comment: Of course you need to implement the setValue function. It's a slot, not a signal.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to do that

Comment: @Engine QSlider valueChanged(int) signal returns integer value. So, your slot must receive int argument that is setValue(int). You can change integer value to double if you want, inside setValue method.

Comment: @d_vj  I know  I need a double value but the SIGNAL needs an int value. But it works now