# how to use QSlider in for a variable

Tags: c++, qt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using QSlider to change the value of a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120165/using-qslider-to-change-the-value-of-a-variable)

I'm trying to use the QSlider to to change a variable value: 
here is a part of the code :

```
 ....
QSlider *slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal,0);
connect(slider,SIGNAL(valueChanged()),this,SLOT(value(int k)));
...
```

the function value is a SLOT that I want to use let's say  like this:

```
 void value (int k ) {
cout<< k << endl;
}
```

the problem that I have is that nothing happens when I move the slider. ?

thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend you reading about signal and slots system in Qt AGAIN, as clearly you didn't understand it well

Comment: No it's not a duplicat , I can use the silder value if I put it with a progress bar but I want to get the position of the slider

Comment: It's exactly same problem but in different place in code. And both problems have exactly same source: you didn't pay attention while you were reading tutorials/docs from Qt

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to put the argument `int` on the signal signature to make it *pass the value to the slot*. Also, never put argument names in the `SIGNAL(...)` / `SLOT(...)` signature specifications.

```
...
QSlider *slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal, this);
connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(value(int)));
...
```

Also, make sure that `value` is a slot of your class, not a free-standing function. I guess you already put the code above in a class function, not in main or any other free-standing function, because in these there is no `this` defined. So the slot you are talking about has to be a member function, especially a QObject slot of the class you are writing this code in. Change

```
void value (int k) {
    cout << k << endl;
}
```

to

```
void MyClass::value (int k) {
    cout << k << endl;
}
```

and in your class definition of `MyClass` add a `public slots:` section:

```
class MyClass : public ... {
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
public slots:
    void value(int);
    ...
}
```

Also, give your slot a meaningful name, for example `sliderChanged`, otherwise, chaos will rule your project sooner or later for sure.

Comment: @Engine Ah, and pass a `parent` to the constructor of the `QSlider`. Otherwise, your application leaks memory. See my edit.

Comment: @Engine Oh, never mind... If you put the slider in a widget afterwards, it's ok to pass `0` in the constructor. Which I'm guessing you do, otherwise you see a single slider in a small window.

Answer (score 0):

From the qt doc:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qabstractslider.html#valueChanged

```
void QAbstractSlider::valueChanged ( int value ) [signal]
```

I'm guessing that at runtime it cannot find the valueChanged() signal, so maybe changing:

```
...
connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(value(int)));
...
```

Hope that helps.